# How do make my e-mail display an image from the web?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, images

I often use inline images in my e-mails, but this often results in very large e-mail sizes that can quickly fill up hard drive space for my recipients.

If I host the image online, I can link to it without including the image data in the e-mail, but then recipients have to click on the link to see the image.

Is there a way to embed an inline image such that the image data is fetched from the internet when my recipient opens the e-mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML in your emails and embed an image with the `<img>` tag. From Outlook, navigate to Tools -> Options. In the "Mail format" tab, Make sure "Compose this message in:" is set to HTML.

example:

```
<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/superuser/Img/wmd-buttons.png">
```

results in:

[image]

Comment: I found out that since Microsoft Office uses a WYSIWYG editor, any html that I try to put in my e-mails is converted to straight text. The help file suggests that I use Microsoft Sharepoint Designer or some other editor.

Comment: It actually turns out that Microsoft Office 2007 broke most html functionality by using Microsoft Word's rendering engine instead of Internet Explorer's. Even if I embed images in this way, it appears that they do not work when loaded in Outlook.

Comment: so you have to use WYSIWYG either way?

Comment: It sounds like in the latest version, you have to use the WYSIWYG editor (because they removed the source editor) and that anyone who receives an html e-mail in the latest Outlook will probably have display problems with it.

Answer (score 2):

> I often use inline images in my
>   e-mails, but this often results in
>   very large e-mail sizes that can
>   quickly fill up hard drive space for
>   my recipients.

What kind of images are we talking about? Diagrams? Proofs? And do they really need to be *in* the e-mail or will they work just fine as a .zip attachment?

I ask only because I've found that 9 times out of 10 the images people want to add don't really *need* to be inline... its just nice if they are. Its a broad generalization, but working as a programmer in the Education department of a rather large health system does show you a good cross-section of users.

> If I host the image online, I can link
>   to it without including the image data
>   in the e-mail, but then recipients
>   have to click on the link to see the
>   image.
>
> Is there a way to embed an inline
>   image such that the image data is
>   fetched from the internet when my
>   recipient opens the e-mail?

You can use an HTML formatted e-mail (all modern clients support it in one way or another) to use a standard HTML image tag to embed the image you have hosted on the web in your e-mail. Directions for this vary from client to client (and to some extent from Outlook version to Outlook version - check out http://office.microsoft.com for directions for your version of Outlook)

Keep in mind that most e-mail clients (Outlook, Thunderbird, GMail, etc.) will initially block the image to protect the users from spammers using the image request to determine if they have a "live" address. If someone doesn't know what's going on they may never know what they are missing. This is a client setting and there is nothing you can do other than include some text explaining what is going on if they don't see an image.

Normally/usually/generally if they add you to a "trusted senders" list (or something to that effect) future images won't be blocked. Useful if this is more than a one-time thing.