# How can I insert a remote image into an email (without attaching it) using Outlook 2007?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, images, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007

I want to insert a jpg picture into an email without attaching it. It exists on the web, so I should be able to just link to it.

[This previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/51407/how-do-make-my-e-mail-display-an-image-from-the-web) has the answer for how to do it in Outlook 2003, but there is no solution that works for Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://superuser.com/a/156161/91656) describes how to use regedit to alter the hidden Outlook setting which allows linking to images without attaching them.

Alternatively, "[ReliefJet Essentials for Microsoft Outlook](http://www.reliefjet.com/Product/Features/OutlookTweaks)" is an app that can achieve the same thing. If you install the trial version of the product, there is a proportion of the product (which allows alteration of the setting in question) that is free even after the trial expires.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used Outlook 2007, but it being similar to 2010, You may be able to go to the Insert tab and click Picture, then Paste the URL in the filename box and click insert.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid it's not that simple. Outlook attaches a copy of the image when I do that.